# How to fix the following error when using Kivy library on PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy

When I wanted to compile a Kivy program using PyCharm, the following error occurred.

sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

However, the Kivy program can be compiled and run on Pydroid. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Kivy isn't installed properly in your PyCharm environment. Reinstall it, being sure to follow the instructions on kivy.org.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by first Kivy and its dependencies.

```
python -m pip uninstall kivy

python -m pip uninstall kivy.deps.sdl2

python -m pip uninstall kivy.deps.glew

python -m pip uninstall kivy.deps.gstreamer

python -m pip uninstall image
```

Now reinstalling everything except gstreamer.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools

python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/packages/simple/

python -m pip install kivy
```